# Case insensitive directory redirect /FOLDER/XXXX and /Folder/XXXX to /folder/XXXX

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

Can't figure this out for the life of me, I simply want to have a certain subdirectory to either forward or always work regardless of its case.

Here is what I currently have (includes a HTTPS redirect)

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
  CheckCaseOnly On
  CheckSpelling On
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/folder/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

This works fine for anything that comes after `/folder/` being case insensitive for some reason, but not "folder" itself.

So `example.com/folder/TESTING` correctly goes to `example.com/folder/testing`, but `example.com/Folder/ANYTHING` will always pull up a 404.

Really only want this to effect that one particular folder if possible, there are a few case sensitive FILES within that directory I'd want to be sure aren't renamed.

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file? From your _substitution_ it looks like this is located at `/folder/.htaccess`? In which case that's the problem. (Although not sure how this prevents files from being _renamed_?)

Comment: That is correct it's located in that folder, so is there no way to do it within that directory without it being in the root?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The `.htaccess` file in that folder is only processed after the folder has been accessed. On a case-sensitive OS, `/FoLdEr/` can't be accessed. You would need to manage this in the root `.htaccess` file.